# Fedora install tomcat 6: No package tomcat6 available

Tags: linux, tomcat, installation, fedora

I want to install the Apache Tomcat 6 on a new Fedora 19 but it does not work.
When I type the following command:

```
yum  install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-admin-web
```

I only get this message:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package tomcat6 available.
No package tomcat6-webapps available.
No package tomcat6-admin-webapps available.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just found the command to install Tomcat 7 (yum install tomcat), but how can I get Tomcat 6?

Comment: Fedora doesn't generally ship _old_ packages.

Comment: oh good to know. I'll now go with a CentOS 6.4 - this will more represent a Server Linux with mature software version -> I don't need always the most recent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all versions of `tomcat` [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/).

The usual way of installing upstream `tomcat` is by unpacking the tarball under `/opt`.

Another approach would be finding a SRPM for tomcat 6 and rebuilding the RPM in a Fedora 19 machine.

Comment: Agreed.  As long as you have the JAVA_PATH environment variable set and a JDK installed, there's really no magic to getting Tomcat running in any environment - I even got it running in an EON system (a stripped-down OpenSolaris distribution that runs in RAM) using this method.

Comment: Ok, but isn't there a package ready to use? I don't want to install it in a directory i choose. This should be as standard as possible

Comment: See @MichaelHampton's comment above for a hint. If you want Tomcat 6 in a Fedora 19 machine, you need to build it yourself and deploy it using a custom/private repository.